# How can I fix my unittest 405 != 200 error when testing my flask application?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, python-unittest

First time using unittests and trying to run and test my flask app. I have the basic things in my Flask app.py:

```
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
port = 5000
@app.route('/',methods=['POST'])
def main():
    data = request.get_json()
```

And in my test.py I have:

```
from app import app
class testing(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False
        app.config['DEBUG'] = False
        self.app = app.test_client()
        self.assertEqual(app.debug, False)

    def tearDown(self):
        pass

    def test_main_page(self):
        response = self.app.get('/', follow_redirects=True)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Keep getting the assertation error 405 != 200
I ran `python -m unittest test.py`
Didn't run. So I tried running `python -m flask run` and then running the unittest in a split terminal but still didnt work. Still new to this so not sure if I'm just missing pieces of code.
I have other unit tests in the code that run and pass but they just check functions and not the actual flask app.

Comment: You only allow POST on that route, but you're sending a GET request. Do you want to instead do: `self.app.post('/',follow_redirects=True)`?

Comment: your app route expects a `POST` but you are sending a `GET`

Comment: 405 means the wrong method being used (GET instead of POST)

Comment: Thanks y'all. Can't believe I didnt catch that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix for a 405 error is that the route is expecting a POST or GET. Depending on your flask app make sure you are using the correct `self.app.post('/',follow_redirects=True)` or `self.app.get('/',follow_redirects=True)`